# How to properly close/terminate a simple Windows app

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Having such a simple DirectX application:

```
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <chrono>
#include "Utils.h"

//#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::chrono;

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = _T("myWindowClass");

// we use a fixed timestep of 1 / (60 fps) = 16 milliseconds
//constexpr std::chrono::nanoseconds timestep(16ms);
constexpr std::chrono::nanoseconds timestep(1000ms);

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

wchar_t msgbuf[100];
int loop_cnt = 0;

bool handle_events() {
    // poll for events

    return false; // true if the user wants to quit the game
}

void update(long long lag) {
    // update game logic here
    swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("update - loop_cnt: %d\n"), loop_cnt++);
    OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

}

void render() {
    // render stuff here
}

VOID OnPaint(HDC hdc) {
}

// ------------ D3D ------------

IDirect3D9* pD3D;
IDirect3DDevice9* pDev;
IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* pVB;

const DWORD OURVERT_FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE;

struct OurVertex {
    float x, y, z;  // pozycja
    float rhw;          // komponent rhw
    D3DCOLOR color; // kolor
};

// -----------------------------

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {

    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Msg = {0};

    std::chrono::nanoseconds lag(0ns);
    auto start_time = clock::now();
    bool quit_game = false;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Registration Failed!"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        _T("The title of my window"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        480,    // initial x size
        640,    // initial y size
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        hInstance, 
        NULL
    );

    OutputDebugString(_T("--> WinMain <-- \n"));

    if (hWnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Creation Failed!"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // ------------ D3D ------------

    pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.Windowed = true;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;

    OurVertex verts[] = {
        { 20.0f, 20.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xffff0000, },
        { 100.0f, 20.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xff00ff00, },
        { 20.0f, 100.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xff00ff55, },
        { 100.0f, 100.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xff0000ff},
    };

    pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &pDev);

    HRESULT hr = pDev->CreateVertexBuffer(4*sizeof(OurVertex), D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, OURVERT_FVF, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &pVB, 0);
    check_HRESULT(_T("CreateVertexBuffer"), hr);

    void* data;

    pVB->Lock(0, 4*sizeof(OurVertex), &data, D3DLOCK_DISCARD);
    memcpy(data, (void*)verts, sizeof(verts));
    pVB->Unlock();

    // -----------------------------


    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (TRUE) {

        while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }

        if (Msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        //  Run game logic

            auto current_time = clock::now();
            auto frame_time = current_time - start_time;
            start_time = current_time;
            lag += duration_cast<nanoseconds>(frame_time);

            // update game logic as lag permits
            while (lag >= timestep) {
                lag -= timestep;

                pDev->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0xff000000, 1, 0);
                pDev->BeginScene();
                pDev->SetFVF(OURVERT_FVF);
                pDev->SetStreamSource(0, pVB, 0, sizeof(OurVertex));
                pDev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
                pDev->EndScene();
                pDev->Present(0, 0, 0, 0);

                update(lag.count()); // update at a fixed rate each time
            }

    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("--> AFTER MSG LOOP END <-- \n"));

    return Msg.wParam;
}

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (msg) {

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i run debug (without any brakpoints defined) i get the output:

```
--> WinMain <-- 
update - loop_cnt: 0
update - loop_cnt: 1
update - loop_cnt: 2
update - loop_cnt: 3
update - loop_cnt: 4
update - loop_cnt: 5
...
```

The program successfully displays a colored rectangle as expected. But, something is going wrong here, because when I click the standard "X" close button in the right upper corner of the app window, the window closes but the program seems not to end properly. I still receive `update - loop_cnt: #` messages in the Output window in my Visual Studio, and there is no `--> AFTER MSG LOOP END <--` message suggesting proper program termination.

What's more, when I try to run debug again, I get an error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open ...Game_Loop_Windows_1.exe for writing
...
MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1168.
1>Done building project "Game_Loop_Windows_1.vcxproj" -- FAILED
```

What can be wrong with the code?

PS. I'm using *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019* on *Windows 10*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message loop likely never terminates.

```cpp
while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}

if (Msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    break;
```

You are handling all messages, but only check that **last** one whether it was a `WM_QUIT` message. Instead, you would need to check all messages and properly exit the loop, something like this:

```cpp
bool running{true};

while (running) {
    while (running && PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        running = Msg.message != WM_QUIT;
    }

    // Not strictly required; you can run another render loop and have
    // the outermost loop exit when running is false
    if (!running)
        break;
```

The link error simply means that the process is still running. An executable image that's mapped into a process cannot be written to. That's what the linker is complaining about.

Comment: Thx for reply. It's trange that the code i presented is invalid. The very similar code (having the same problem as mine, only checking the last message) is presented on the Direct X Tutorial http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-1-4 site...

Comment: Does that mean that the code presented there is also not valid?

Comment: If it's the same code then it is broken for the same reason. The defect is easy to miss, since everything appears to work. Until you recompile. Guess this is just another manifestation of The First Rule of Programming: Every code you find in the internet is garbage.

Comment: Yes, You are right friend:-) Thx for pointing me the problem. One thing is still making me wonder  - how could it be that after sending the WM_QUIT message the system is still sending other, extra messages?

Comment: [`WM_QUIT` is a low-priority message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453) so the only trailing messages would need to be low-priority as well. [WM_NCMOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-ncmousemove) would be one such candidate, or timer messages. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) explains, *"When the thread retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message from its message queue, it should exit its message loop"*. The code in this answer just follows the contract.

Comment: So as far as i get the WM_QUIT i should immediately exit the message loop just safely ignoring all the messages pushed after the WM_QUIT?

Comment: That's how the system is designed to be used, and ignoring trailing messages isn't special. That's what applications using a more traditional `while(GetMessage(...))` loop are doing all the time.